# Zero-fee transactions

Tags: node, tezos-client, protocol

Need so help to understand the below transaction :

```
[
    {
        "type": "transaction",
        "id": 279,
        "level": 26,
        "timestamp": "2018-06-30T18:07:27Z",
        "hash": "opDckVrXacor6B25F3SD2epxC13iCoN6xjwsvvJDYo5aa9AMbqz",
        "counter": 5,
        "originalSender": {
            "address": "tz1NKVAxzJusWgKewn4LEViPSQVRE5Kg6XFV"
        },
        "sender": {
            "alias": "Vested funds 5",
            "address": "KT1Um7ieBEytZtumecLqGeL56iY6BuWoBgio"
        },
        "nonce": 0,
        "gasLimit": 0,
        "gasUsed": 107,
        "storageLimit": 0,
        "storageUsed": 0,
        "bakerFee": 0,
        "storageFee": 0,
        "allocationFee": 0,
        "target": {
            "alias": "Foundation baker 8",
            "address": "tz3NExpXn9aPNZPorRE4SdjJ2RGrfbJgMAaV"
        },
        "amount": 199041301565,
        "parameters": "{\"prim\":\"Unit\"}",
        "status": "applied",
        "hasInternals": false
    }
```

Please help me validate my understanding

Address - `KT1Um7ieBEytZtumecLqGeL56iY6BuWoBgio` has "X" tez.

with the above transaction `KT1Um7ieBEytZtumecLqGeL56iY6BuWoBgio` has transferred `199041301565` tezos to target `tz3NExpXn9aPNZPorRE4SdjJ2RGrfbJgMAaV`.

1. Amount left with `KT1Um7ieBEytZtumecLqGeL56iY6BuWoBgio = ("X" - ( 199041301565 + bakerFee))` - Is my assumption correct in this case?
2. Why is the baker fee zero in this case ?

Comment: One remark: The unit of transfert is mutez not tez. 1 mutez (micro-tez)  is 1e-6 xtz so the notional of this transfert is approximately 199k xtz. You can check it on tzkt here https://tzkt.io/opDckVrXacor6B25F3SD2epxC13iCoN6xjwsvvJDYo5aa9AMbqz

Answer (score 5):

**1. No, it's not correct.**

There are two types of operations in Tezos: `ordinary` and `internal` (aka a result of smart contracts execution). If there is a `nonce` field or `originalSender` field, then it's an `internal` operation.

In case of internal operation, original sender pays for all the fees, so here is the correct code:

```
if (tx.originalSender != null)
{
    tx.sender.Balance -= tx.amount;
    tx.originalSender.Balance -= tx.storageFee + tx.allocationFee;
    //bakerFee in internal operations is always 0
}
else
{
    tx.sender.Balance -= tx.amount + tx.bakerFee + tx.storageFee + tx.allocationFee;
}
```

**2. In this particular case `bakerFee` is 0, because it's an internal operation.**

But it may be 0 even if it's not an internal operation (sender can set any fee value). Also, on the early blocks many operations have zero fee...

Comment: the above transaction sample has an original sender field that means the transaction is initiated by original sender but what the role of sender field in this case

Comment: Sender transfers its funds

Comment: if i understand it correct sender is a originated account (KT1Um7ieBEytZtumecLqGeL56iY6BuWoBgio) which is derived from implicit account(tz1NKVAxzJusWgKewn4LEViPSQVRE5Kg6XFV) referred as original sender.





2. So if my understanding is true then the funds which the originated account aka sender is sending to target is the amount which have been transferred from impilicit account aka original sender to sender some time during a delegation operation.

Comment: `KT1Um7ieBEytZtumecLqGeL56iY6BuWoBgio` is a smart contract (originated account), but it wasn't derived from `tz1NKVAxzJusWgKewn4LEViPSQVRE5Kg6XFV`, but was bootstrapped during blockchain initialization. Look at detailed account history on TzKT: https://tzkt.io/KT1Um7ieBEytZtumecLqGeL56iY6BuWoBgio/operations. And `tz1NKVAxzJusWgKewn4LEViPSQVRE5Kg6XFV` is just the one who invoked the smart contract, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

**I've edited my answer to take into account the answer of Groxan.**

1. Yes, the contract `KT1...` that is the emitter of the internal transaction only pays the amount of the transaction. However, as detailed below in the answer of [Groxan](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/2163/1773), fees are payed by the original sender.

Now follows a discussion on other cases where the fees of the outer transaction may have zero fees:

There is no fixed baker fee. Instead, when someone injects a transaction onto the network, they propose a fee. [A baker is free to accept, or not, to bake that transactions for the given fee](http://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtouse.html#transfers-and-receipts):

> Another interesting thing we learn from the receipt is that there are
> more costs being added on top of the transfer and the burn: fees. In
> order to encourage a baker to include our operation, and in general to
> pay for the cost of running the blockchain, each operation usually
> includes a fee that goes to the baker. Fees are variable over time and
> depend on many factors but the tezos client selects a default for us.

Lets try this out in a sandbox. When submitting a transaction using `tezos-client`, we can set the fee using the `--fee` flag (search "--fee" in the [CLI reference](http://tezos.gitlab.io/api/cli-commands.html)):

```
$ tezos-client transfer 100 from bootstrap1 to bootstrap2 --fee 0
Node is bootstrapped, ready for injecting operations.
Estimated gas: 10207 units (will add 100 for safety)
Estimated storage: no bytes added
Fatal error:
  The proposed fee (ꜩ0) are lower than the fee that baker expect by default (ꜩ0.001281).
   Use `--force-low-fee` to emit this operation anyway.
```

The client complains about the low fee, but we can force it with `--force-low-fee`:

```
tezos-client transfer 100 from bootstrap1 to bootstrap2 --fee 0 --force-low-fee
```

The transactions is now injected, but the command will wait until it has been validated by a baker.
In a separate terminal, let's bake it:

```
$ tezos-client bake for bootstrap3
Feb 17 14:34:27 - alpha.baking.forge: found 0 valid operations (1 refused) for timestamp 2020-02-17T13:34:27-00:00 (fitness 01::0000000000000001)
```

The baker refuses transactions because of the low fee. But we can force it by setting minimum fees requires:

```
$ tezos-client bake for bootstrap3 --minimal-fees 0 --minimal-nanotez-per-gas-unit 0 --minimal-nanotez-per-byte 0
Feb 17 14:37:41 - alpha.baking.forge: found 1 valid operations (0 refused) for timestamp 2020-02-17T13:37:41-00:00 (fitness 01::0000000000000004)
```

We get the following receipt:

```
Operation found in block: BMRSeaNGPB5AfqzqEVkdnEBzJfNCoP9WyXK2zZTY18H9hvrcx1H (pass: 3, offset: 0)
This sequence of operations was run:
  Manager signed operations:
    From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
    Fee to the baker: ꜩ0
    Expected counter: 1
    Gas limit: 10307
    Storage limit: 0 bytes
    Transaction:
      Amount: ꜩ100
      From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
      To: tz1gjaF81ZRRvdzjobyfVNsAeSC6PScjfQwN
      This transaction was successfully applied
      Consumed gas: 10207
      Balance updates:
        tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx ... -ꜩ100
        tz1gjaF81ZRRvdzjobyfVNsAeSC6PScjfQwN ... +ꜩ100
```

We can find the transaction in the RPC and compare it to what you've got:

```
$ tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/operations/3
[ { "protocol": "ProtoALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaDdp3zK",
    "chain_id": "NetXdQprcVkpaWU",
    "hash": "opYqCQPfhDEMGeCrTa55XrHTFrQweThEFNSTQuWpUVVgKzGDHt3",
    "branch": "BLfZzHax3gG7GyQzee6AqS6UremB9hJpidqRpmo56FoLRiRaj6Z",
    "contents":
      [ { "kind": "transaction",
          "source": "tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx", "fee": "0",
          "counter": "1", "gas_limit": "10307", "storage_limit": "0",
          "amount": "100000000",
          "destination": "tz1gjaF81ZRRvdzjobyfVNsAeSC6PScjfQwN",
          "metadata":
            { "balance_updates": [],
              "operation_result":
                { "status": "applied",
                  "balance_updates":
                    [ { "kind": "contract",
                        "contract": "tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx",
                        "change": "-100000000" },
                      { "kind": "contract",
                        "contract": "tz1gjaF81ZRRvdzjobyfVNsAeSC6PScjfQwN",
                        "change": "100000000" } ], "consumed_gas": "10207" } } } ],
    "signature":
      "sigvyNn4gV5N4hC9VyGMq5rCZ62mNp1pn6GYPH57WM2PLh8UV6WNJDQ7sNKzD8dsc1ndfTodqYpCtMSrH7ptsP8cgL4jWo1m" } ]
```

As you can see, the fee is 0.

However in the case of your question, the reason is that the transaction is internal, as detailed below in the answer of [Groxan](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/2163/1773).

Comment: Thanks . Your explanation makes complete sense to me but i have one quick question as per the above analogy if the sender, target and baker are the same entity then they can approve any of the  transactions(malicious/bad) into the block. And if this happens then blockchain data is compromised in this case. How does it actually work in case of tezos .Kindly help

Comment: Hi, turns out my explanation was wrong, the one of Groxan is the correct one for your case. However, 0-fee transactions can still be validated as my examples demonstrate. There are several mechanisms put in place to ensure that bakers do not cheat: notably, they pay a deposit that is retained if cheating is detected. Also, a system of endorsements and accusations are used. You can read more here: http://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html#baking
if you have a more specific scenario of cheating in mind, I can give more specifics.

Comment: i understood your example but in balance_updates section why the kind is mentioned as contract . tz1 accounts are not contracts .caould you please help me understnd

Comment: In tezos, both tz1 and KT1's are referred to as contracts. Tz1 are called "implicit accounts" and kt1 are called originated accounts. But in general, a contract can be either a kt1 or a tz1.